# 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column' for Inherited Field

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa

I am getting a 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column...' error when trying to save my Person object. It's being set properly as far as I can tell (after printing out the value), but it's failing on the save command.

The field that it cannot insert a null for is an inherited field from another class.

Here is my model:

```
public class BaseDomain
{
    ... 

    @Column(name="LST_UPD_PRG") private String lastUpdateProgram;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PRSN_INF")
public class Person extends BaseDomain
{
    ...

    @Column(name="FRS_NM") private String firstName;
    @Column(name="LST_NM") private String lastName;
}
```

And then I'm attempting to save the person like so"

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     ... 

     Person person = new Person();

     person.setFirstName("John");
     person.setLastName("Doe");
     person.setLastUpdateProgram("BatchJob_01");

     personRepository.save(person);
}
```

And then, the save operation throws the error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LST_UPD_PRG'...
```

I initially created the BaseDomain class because each of the tables in the database will have the LST_UPD_PRG column. Is there something wrong with the way I'm doing inheritence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the @MappedSuperclass annotation on the BaseDomain class.  Adding that annotation will hopefully resolve your issue.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseDomain {
...
```

Comment: That took care of it. I'm both happy and sad it was so simple!